# Aquiring Triangular Signal Equation from Waveform

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, wave-equation

I've looked everywhere and even the textbook does not explain how to do this.
This is probably very simple, yet I can't figure it out.

[image]

How do you derive the expression at the bottom for the periods? Is there a specific equation?

Comment: break the given wave into 3 pieces : $0\to 1$ ,  $1\to 3$ and $3 \to 4$

Comment: I can do that, sorry I shouldve mentioned that in my question. I can break into pieces and get the values if its a DC signal but I don't know how for triangular.

Comment: Can you write the equation of a straight line using $\text{slope}$ and a $\text{point}$ ?

Comment: y=mx+c correct??

Comment: yes ! whats the equation of straight line in first interval ? 
($0\to 1$). Notice that it is rising $50V$ in $1$ second. So the slope would be $\dfrac{50}{1} = 50$.

Comment: Oh yes. yes. I should... go back to school. I cant believe I forgot this..
$$Y-0=50x-0$$

I wasn't taught math in English so I didn't know the proper terms to look this up again..

Comment: yes that equation is correct ! hope you can manage figuring out the remaining two equations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ m = \frac{ y_{2} -y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}} $$

$$y-y_{1}=m(x-x_{1})$$

Thanks to @ganeshie8.